# What is the optimal temperature for Omicron to thrive in?

Tags: coronavirus, immune-system

I have always been under the impression that when sick, you should let a fever run its course. The accepted answer to the question [Why do people take drugs to lower a fever?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/7541/if-fever-is-a-natural-immune-defense-why-do-people-take-drugs-to-lower-it) seems to provide some support for the theory and cites [optimal temperature](https://medlineplus.gov/ency/article/003090.htm) which says that most bacteria and viruses thrive best at 98.6 F. I was wondering how much variance there is to this optimal temperature and if some bacteria and virus infections can thrive at hotter temperatures? If so, I would think that studying the optimal thriving temperatures for various bacteria and viruses (including omicron) would be important to decide whether to treat, or let a fever run. With a quick google search I could not find any studies on the optimal temperature for omicron.

Comment: I think it's fine for this question to stand as a Biology question, but I think it asks the wrong thing if it's intending to use this as support for "should a fever be treated or not"; see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem and https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/57974/27148

Comment: Omikron is really new, don't expect comprehensive data on it. Even with SARS-CoV2, there is still much to learn and I am not aware of any "optimal temperature" studies (and I can't even imagine a design of such a study).